# Not optimal PHP configuration detected on this machine

Tags: php, iis, configuration

I'm trying to install PHPmyadmin in IIS 8, seem not success, because PHPmanager said "Not optimal PHP configuration detected on this machine". what does it mean? Anyone can help me to make PHPmyadmin works in IIS 8? Thank you!

Gary

Comment: are you sure that's the *exact* error message?

Comment: Yeah, that is what it said in PHP manager in IIS 8.

Comment: i searched every PHPmyadmin file and that text does not appear

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but maybe IIS and phpmyadmin are running on same port 80(default for both IIS and apache server).

Change the apache service for to something other than 80.

Look for line Listen 80 in apache configuration file and change it.

Answer (score 0):

Does your IIS 8 support phpMyAdmin's [requirements](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Requirements)? Check that carefully. I had similar problem, read requirements, reconfigured sever - and et voilà! Check also ports - phpMyAdmin port has to be other that IIS port.

> Session support. Make sure that sessions are configured properly (see
>   below) and session.cookie_secure is Off if you are not using a secure
>   connection (i.e. "https")
>       Either the mysql or mysqli extensions (more details)
>
> ```
> The mbstring extension
> GD2 support in PHP to display inline thumbnails of JPEGs ("image/jpeg: inline") with their original aspect ratio 
>
> PHP 4.3.0 or newer is needed to use the "text/plain: external" MIME-based transformation 
>
> If you are using the Hardened PHP Suhosin extension make sure to increase the values for suhosin.request|get|post.max_* see also
> ```
>
> Suhosin Configuration and Hardened-PHP request limits. You can examine
>   some increased suhosin.x values on the demo server -> main page ->
>   Show PHP information, e.g., suhosin.post.max_value_length and
>   suhosin.request.max_value_length = 128000 . See also FAQ 1.38. Another
>   such obstacle is "mod_security" on fedora boxes, error: "Method Not
>   Implemented. GET ..."; a possible solution:
>   http://forums.theplanet.com/index.php?showtopic=89327 .
>
> ```
> If any paths are defined in your php.ini like session.save_path or upload_tmp_dir make sure that they do exist and your os is able to
> ```
>
> write to them. Especially on a Windows system "/tmp" does not exist by
>   default! Due to a broken WIN PHP 5.2 installer paths are definitely
>   wrong in that version bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39842. Using IIS as
>   webserver you also need an user named "IUSR" or "IUSR_MACHINENAME"
>   with r/w/modify rights granted on those folders.
>
> ```
> Not really a requirement but a strong suggestion: if you are using the cookie authentication method, having the mcrypt PHP extension on
> ```
>
> your web server accelerates not only the login phase but every other
>   action that you do in phpMyAdmin
>
> ```
> On 64 bit systems the mcrypt PHP extension is required for auth_type "cookie". The alternative blowfish routines only work on
> ```
>
> 32-bit systems at the moment (due to a PHP 5.2.0/1 bug, should be
>   fixed in PHP 5.2.2 meanwhile). The same issue leads to the cryptic
>   "#1045 access denied for user www-data.." messages on Ubuntu boxes.
>
> ```
> If you have weird random problems also check out whether apc or eaccelerator is the culprit. If the problem is with APC it's possible
> ```
>
> to prevent scripts in the phpMyAdmin directory from being cached with
>   apc.filters. For instance you can add something like this to your
>   php.ini: apc.filters = "-/usr/share/phpmyadmin/.*"